# Java unit testing with parameter

Tags: java, unit-testing

In C#, it is possible to specify parameters for the same unit test method.
Example:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(12,3,4)]
[DataRow(12,2,6)]
public void DivideTest(int n, int d, int q)
{
   Assert.AreEqual( q, n / d );
}
```

Is it possible to do the same in Java? I have read Parametrized runner but this solution is not as easy to use.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1822315/335858)

Comment: Have you had a look at [parameterized tests](https://blog.codefx.org/libraries/junit-5-parameterized-tests/) in [JUnit 5](http://junit.org/junit5/)?

Comment: This is not a Java feature but a framework feature. I particularly like the way that Spock handles it, but both JUnit and TestNG have support, too.

Comment: I read TestNG is no more maintained. It is true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With JUnit 5, parameterized tests are really more straight and natural to use as with JUnit 4.

In your case, to provide multiple parameters as input, you could use the `@CsvSource` annotation.

Here are the required dependencies (maven declaration way) :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0-M4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0-M4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And here is a sample code (with required imports) :

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvSource;

public class YourTestClass{

    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource({ "12,3,4", "12,2,6" })
    public void divideTest(int n, int d, int q) {
       Assert.assertEquals(q, n / d);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Spock Framewok](http://spockframework.org/) offers [Data Driven Testing](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/data_driven_testing.html) for Java and Groovy.

The Tests are (*unfortunately?*) written in Groovy:

> ```
> class MathSpec extends Specification {
>   def "maximum of two numbers"() {
>     expect:
>     Math.max(a, b) == c
>
>     where:
>     a | b || c
>     1 | 3 || 3
>     7 | 4 || 7
>     0 | 0 || 0
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve this so simple with `JUnit` out of the box, but you can use 3rd party [JUnitParams](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams):

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class PersonTest {

  @Test
  @Parameters({"17, false", 
               "22, true" })
  public void personIsAdult(int age, boolean valid) throws Exception {
    assertThat(new Person(age).isAdult(), is(valid));
  }

  @Test
  public void lookNoParams() {
    etc
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan. Much better. Since Java8, annotations could be repeatable. Do you know if the same solution exists by repeating @Parameters?

Comment: You mean, will it work for several annotated methods? Yes, it will.

Comment: @Ivan Pronin +1 as nice alternative before Junit 5.

Answer (score 0):

yes, eg. JUnit has parameterized tests

https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/parameterized-tests

The only drawback is that all test methods in the class will be executed for each parameter (row).

Comment: Thanks Timothy, but as I said, I don't like this solution. The reason is parameters and testing methods are too distinct. That is why I think it is not as easy to use than C# solution.